# Security Error in Silverlight Application

Tags: crossdomain.xml, clientaccesspolicy.xml

i have deployed my silverlight app, service and database all in different server. but when trying to run app, got security error. after doing researches, there are mostly the same solution which is about clientaccesspolicy.xml and crossdomain.xml. so, i have created these 2 files and put this in inetpub/wwwroot/ for all servers. but i still got the error. pls help me...what should i do now? should my app be put in inetpub/wwwroot/ too?, since now it is located in different drive.

clientaccesspolicy.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<access-policy>  
    <cross-domain-access>  
        <policy>  
            <allow-from http-request-headers="SOAPAction">  
                <!-- IMPORTANT! Include these lines -->
                <domain uri="http://*"/>  
                <domain uri="https://*"/>  
            </allow-from>  
            <grant-to>  
                <resource path="/" include-subpaths="true"/>  
            </grant-to>  
        </policy>  
    </cross-domain-access>  
</access-policy>
```

crossdomain.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
  <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="SOAPAction,Content-Type"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Comment: Post the error you get please.

Comment: i only get alert textbox "Security Error"

Comment: i added this in web config to display detail error but still got the same error.haih... <configuration>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>

Comment: through fiddler, i got this error 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.

Comment: Is your web app stored in a virtual directory? Try putting the files in the root of the app folder.